# Как в Ansible из двух массивов получить третий?

Tags: linux, администрирование, ansible

Есть 2 массива:

```json
"names_fact": [
    "site1", 
    "site1"
]
```

и

```
"tiers_fact": [
    "prod", 
    "test"
]
```

Мне нужно получить третий:

```
"lxd_containers_names_fact": [
    "site1-test",
    "site1-prod"
]
```

Я пытался понять что написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487241) (вроде мой случай) и адаптировать, но ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось как обычно максимально просто:

```yaml
- name: Set lxd_containers_names_fact fact
  when: ansible_system == 'Linux'
  block:
    - set_fact:
        lxd_containers_names_fact: []
    - set_fact:
        lxd_containers_names_fact:
          "{{ lxd_containers_names_fact + [ item.0 + '-' + item.1 ] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ names_fact }}"
        - "{{ tiers_fact }}"
```